# Do I need a separate Heroku account for each application on a paid plan?

Tags: heroku

I've created a site on Heroku for a friend, and he wants https, so I'm looking at upgrading to the hobby plan to enable this for him.

I also run a couple of other friends' sites from the same Heroku account. They're not particularly interested in https.

If I upgrade to the hobby plan, do all applications on the account get https? And how does the whole dyno thing work - are they shared between the various applications on my single account, or allocated to a specific application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need a separate account for each application on a paid plan?

You can have 5 applications per account when not verified, and 200 for verified accounts. Other limits are in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits).

> If I upgrade to the hobby plan do all applications on the account get https?

They *can*, it's an account-level feature. It's recommended that you do so anyways; the new browser default to make insecure sites look insecure may deter traffic from your sites. It doesn't really matter if you "need" it, it's completely free, so there's no real reason not to.

> And how does the whole dyno thing work - are they shared between the various applications on my single account, or allocated to a specific application?

Dynos are shared across your account, but allocated to specific applications. So, for example, if you have three sites running, you'll need at least 3 dynos to cover the usage for that if they run the entire month. If one site is running slow, you can add additional dynos to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answers, much appreciated. Just to be clear, is the following correct: in order to add https I need to upgrade to a paid plan -> to do this I pay for one dyno ($7/month) and allocate this to the specific application that I want https on - this will enable https for that application alone -> other applications will continue running as normal (on free dynos and without https)?

Comment: @J.Davies keep in mind that free apps go to sleep every day, and have a limited number of hours. You may need to upgrade to hobby level sooner than you think. You get at most 1,000 hours across all your free dynos, which means you can't even run two apps on the free tier for the entire month. You basically "get one free", and you're expected to pay for more afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, yes the two sites I've been maintaining receive relatively little traffic so have both got by on the free dynos so far. However the traffic has been picking up noticeably recently so hopefully upgrading the one will free up the free traffic for the other!

Comment: Clarification - upgrading an app to hobby dynos will not give all apps in the account HTTPS. The dynos (ie the plan) you choose to use are per app not account - you scale up dynos on the apps resource page. You can have a mixture of apps with free, hobby, standard, perf dyno's. The features you can use per app are dictated by the types of dynos it runs. J.Davies - your assumption above is correct.